# Spark UI appears with wrong format (broken CSS)

Tags: css, apache-spark, user-interface, localhost, google-cloud-dataproc

I am using Apache Spark for the first time. I run my application and when I access `localhost:4040` I get what is shown in the picture. 
I found that maybe setting

```
spark.ui.enabled true
```

could help but I don't know how to do that.

[image: UI view]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same issue while using Spark on Google Cloud Dataproc.

If you will access Spark Job UI not through `4040` port directly, but through YARN Web UI (`8088` port) you will see correctly rendered web pages.

To workaround this issue when accessing Spark UI directly through `4040` port you need to reset `spark.ui.proxyBase` property inside your Spark job (not in CLI/job submission command), because it gets overridden by Spark UI proxy:

```scala
sys.props.update("spark.ui.proxyBase", "")
```

[Here is](https://laujohn.com/2018/09/22/Apache-Spark-Web-UI-on-Amazon-EMR/) detailed description of this issue.

Comment: I am using 8088. But it still has this issue

Comment: @codinglover in this case you need to create a new SO question and describe an issue that you have, your comment is not useful at all...

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem. 
Also the calls to http://localhost:4040/api/v1/applications failed returning with no response.

This happened due to a collision between 2 versions of Jersey in my classpath.
Mainly conflict between 1.x and 2.x.
What worked for me was to exclude in my Maven build the Jersey library that came from other dependencies that are not from Spark.

For example:

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
          <artifactId>parquet-avro</artifactId>
          <version>1.9.0</version> 

          <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                  <artifactId>*</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Excluding version Jersey 1.x (My Spark distro used 2.x) solved the problem.

Edit:

Also -> happened when servlet api 2.5 JAR was in classpath instead or together with 3.x

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using WildFly, see if https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27795 can help (there you find also (a quite ugly) workaround).

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem and tried with `sys.props.update("spark.ui.proxyBase", "")`. Spark UI was fixed but it was still triggering errors in logs for wrong CSS related to `javax`.

I added below dependency and it fixed all errors:

```
libraryDependencies += "javax.servlet" % "servlet-api" % "2.5" % "provided"
```